# How to calculate percentage in sql which result will appear in different columns?

Tags: sql, sas

I have to calculate percentage based on different ranking class which is 1st or 2nd. Below is a sample data table.

```
Year   Grading_PerID  Candidate_ID   Ranking
-----  ------------   ------------   -------
2007        1              1            1  
2007        1              1            2
2007        2              2            1
2007        3              2            1
2008        4              1            2
2008        3              2            1
2008        2              2            2 
2008        1              1            2
2009        2              1            1   
2009        3              1            2
2009        4              2            1
2009        1              2            1
```

I want to calculate from 2007 to 2009, how many times candidate_1 and candidate_2 are graded in each year and the proportions are respectively that candidate_1 and candidate_2 are graded as 1st and 2nd. The expecting output sample is given below:

Expecting Out Put :

```
Candidate_ID   Year   Count    1_rank   2_rank
------------   ----   -----    ------   ------
     1         2007     2         %        %
     1         2008     2         %        %
     1         2009     2         %        %
     2         2007     2         %        %
     2         2008     2         %        %
     2         2009     2         %        %
```

I have done the part without rank percentages by using the sql below:

```
select candidate_id , year, count(*) as count                    
from myTable                                   
group by candidate_id, year;
```

But I have no idea on how to calculate the ranking percentage for each year. How could I do to achieve that?

Comment: Please tag RDBMS name.. SQL Server/MySQL/ORACLE..

Comment: For future reference, you will get a better answer faster, and save the SO community a lot of time, by tagging your question with the appropriate version of SQL you are using.

Comment: SAS SQL is a flavour of SQL. It isn't dependent on the version unless using direct pass through to the server, which the OP is not doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM(CASE WHEN ...)` to conditionally count the number of 1 and 2 ranks for each group:

```
select candidate_id, year, count(*) as count,
    100*SUM(case when Ranking = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS 1_rank,
    100*SUM(case when Ranking = 2 then 1 else 0 end) AS 2_rank,
from myTable                                   
group by candidate_id, year;
```

Comment: Should it be 100*(SUM(IF(Ranking == 1)) / count(*)) AS 1_rank, 100*(SUM(IF(Ranking == 2)) / count(*)) AS 2_rank?

Comment: My one has error with '==' sign, it says: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant.

Comment: @TasteMyBiceps Good catch.  I removed the extra equals sign.  Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Then it says:  Function IF could not be located. Can it be achieve by using sub query instead of sum(if())?

Comment: Emmm, actually it is the `proc sql` in SAS.

Comment: Updated my answer _again_.  Try using `case when`.

Comment: Omg, The problem solved. Thank you so much! This `case when` saved me!

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding ranking percentage is how many time in a year a candidate is allocated with rank 1 or 2. for eg.  in 2008 candidate 1 is assigned to rank 2 two times. SO rank 2 percentage will be 100% in his case and rank 1 percentage will be 0.
Below is my query, let me know if you have any doubt

create table mytable (yr number,grade_id number,c_id number,rank number);

```
select a.c_id,a.yr,cnt1,NVL((b.cnt2/a.cnt1) * 100,0) rnk_1_percentage,NVL((c.cnt2/a.cnt1) * 100,0) rnk_2_percentage
from 
(select yr,c_id,count(*) cnt1 from mytable group by yr,c_id ) a,
(select yr,c_id,rank,count(*) cnt2 from mytable where rank=1 group by yr,c_id,rank ) b,
(select yr,c_id,rank,count(*) cnt2 from mytable where rank=2 group by yr,c_id,rank) c
where a.yr=b.yr(+)
and a.c_id=b.c_id(+)
and a.yr=c.yr(+)
and a.c_id=c.c_id(+)
order by a.yr;
```

OR

In oracle it is like below in support to @Tim Biegeleisen

```
select yr,c_id
,100*(SUM(decode(rank,1,1,0)) / count(*))  rank1
,100*(SUM(decode(rank,2,1,0)) / count(*)) rank2
 from mytable group by yr,c_id
```

Comment: why is rank == 2,1,0 and 1,1,1, not rank == 1 and rank ==2?

Comment: its decode function in oracle, it works like below
decode(rank,1,1,0) this means
if (rank=1) then return 1 else 0